# sbt throws error: org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4: not found

Tags: scala, sbt

When i build my project, I got the following error:

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
error] Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang/jline/2.10.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang/jline/2.10.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.4/jline-2.10.4.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4
```

My plugins.sbt :

```
logLevel := Level.Warn
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")
```

scalaVersion = 2.11.7

sbt.version  = 0.13.5

Intellij IDEA 2021.3.3 (Community Edition)

Probably I have a problem with my resolver but I dont know where i can fix this problem.

Im a beginner btw...

Comment: You have defined your resolver address as `http://...`, try defining using https instead.